# Using PageViewController for a large number of pages like camera roll image view?

Tags: ios, uiview, uicollectionview, uipageviewcontroller

I am trying to create an app for which I need a way to swipe through views. For example, while swiping through images in photo stream or camera roll. I DO NOT need to swipe through images however, I need to swipe through `UIViews`. I have been looking at `PageViewController`. However, `setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:` suggests that I need a `ViewController` for every `UIView`. This doesn't seem to be what I want since I will have over 40 views that I will need to scroll through. I think I'm missing an obvious ios feature here since even iBooks has a way to go through pages of books.

I was thinking maybe having 3 `ViewControllers` and changing their content whenever I swipe across. But that seems very roundabout.

Please help me out!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple has provided a fairly robust example of doing this kind of thing with photos called "PhotoScroller" at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html. It uses UIScrollViews and CATiledLayers to recreate the experience of the Photos app. You may be able to modify it to work with your UIViews instead of images.

Comment: Also, the scroll views talk from WWDC 2012 shows how to massively simplify said sample code using UIPageViewController. Check the [video](http://developer.apple.com/videos).